# SSH to a virtual machine

Tags: ssh, virtualbox, virtual-machine, nat

I recently installed a Linux (Mint 17) virtual Machine on a Windows 7 PC. In order to be able to SSH to this virtual machine, I had to define a few rules and redirect ports as explained in other posts of this very forum (see [this link](https://superuser.com/questions/424083/virtualbox-host-ssh-to-guest) for instance).

I realized that there is a known bug on virtual box regarding the drop of TCP connections (see [this ticket](https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/12441)). After updating the **natdnshostresolver1** however, I still experience loss of TCP connections after about 10 to 12 minutes.

The virtualmachine is still on and can still access the internet but it is impossible to ssh to it. From the virtual machine, I can ssh to any other machine, it is only the "input" ssh that is not working.

Does anyone know if this is a known issue with VirtualBox ? I am using version **4.3.20** of the software.

Comment: I have never experienced this issue, but I can tell you from my experience networking misconfiguration is the #1 reason that *anything* doesn't work in a Virtualbox.

Comment: Sounds like a ports/NAT problem - have you considered using bridged networking? It eliminates some of these issues by connecting your VM directly to the network.

Comment: I did not consider using bridged networking, I will try that. I did not assume it could be a port issue as this problem only occurs after a certain time...

Comment: Ok, so indeed with a bridged connection it seems to be working fine, no more loss of connection. Thanks for the tip !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure af the exact cause of your woes, but networking virtual machines can be complicated. Your computer is acting as a NAT router for your VM(s), and so it has to manage port forwarding and address translation, among many other things.

One way of eliminating these problems can be to use bridged networking instead. Instead of providing address translation, your computer uses a series of tricks to share your network card between the virtual and real machines. Each has its own IP on the network, through one physical connection.

VirtualBox, Parallels, and most VMware products (Fusion, Player etc.) have an option to enable bridged networking.